# Managing asynchronous periodic data updates in iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, timer, updates

I suppose this is a pretty common scenario, but I don't find what the best practices to handle it should be. I need to perform a polling to a server by a network call every X hours, in order to get updates of the app's core data, and I need this operation to be unobtrusive and to avoid blocking the UI (but I'd need to show some kind of "updating" indicator at some place of the current view).

How should I manage this? Should I create an `NSTimer` within the `AppDelegate`? Then, what considerations should I have regarding the `NSRunLoop` for the timer? Is there another and better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Will the app need to update while it is backgrounded?

Comment: Yes, it should keep updating even in background